# Anything Python related causes crash to ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.3

**Problem:** ArcMap 10.3 crashes to desktop anytime I use a Python related function (Toolboxes, Field Calulator, Etc)

**How I got to this point:** I was trying to gain some familiarity with Python programming and opted to use the guide of [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/index.html).
This involved downloading, installing Python and setting your environment using Powershell.
I believe this caused some issues since there was already an installation of Python in effect from having ArcGIS Installed. There was already a "Python27" folder on my main HDD.

**Question:** How do I tell my ArcMap to look in the "Python27\ArcGIS10.3" folder for Python? I'd prefer to avoid re-installing ArcGIS entirely.

**Screenshots for thought:**
[image]
^ From initial research, I found that I should have some sort of Python directory entered into these fields, but I'm not sure what specifically needs to go in there.

[image]

Comment: Your fastest path to productivity is to uninstall Desktop, uninstall Python, and reinstall Desktop w/ Python.  Configuring site packages probably doesn't come until later in your book.

Comment: I've had similar problems while building scripts and having lots and lots of failed runs.  One thing I found was that opening up ArcCatalog and clearing out the geoprocessing results made things work again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve the issue I did the following:

- Deleted extra installs/instances of Python outside of my ArcGIS10.3 folder.
- Reset my environment by following the steps in "Learn Python The Hard Way" by telling it to look in "Python27\ArcGIS10.3"
- Used "Repair Program" from the Setup application within the main folder for ArcGIS\Desktop

Things seem to be stable and operational now.

Comment: There is a good chance that, in the process of following your guide, you either updated ```numpy``` on the version of python installed with ArcGIS (and the update was rolled back by "Repair Program") or you pointed ArcGIS to a python installation with an updated "normal" version of ```numpy```. ArcGIS uses a custom version of ```numpy```, and will crash in the manner you described if you attempt to use a version other than the custom version that comes with ArcGIS.

Comment: Is this the best anyone can come up with? What If I already use a particular version of Python and want to use ArcGIS separately? Does ArcGIS expect us to only have the specific version they are using?